# Azure Continuous Deployment ignoring image files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I set up continuous deployment for my app service on Azure. When I push changes to my repo (on Azure Devops), Azure deploys my changes except for the image files. It's like it's ignoring .jpg files but pushing the rest. I also confirmed the image files to exist in my repository on the server and that Azure's continuous deployment feature tried to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Solution Explorer and find image file(s) there.
2. Right-click on the file and open properties.
3. Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".
4. Build project and make sure that images has been copied

Answer (score 0):

I found out my .csproj ignored the file. I just right clicked the file in Visual Studio and changed the properties to not exclude the file.